# How would I implement retrieving user details with spring security using using spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-security

So I want to make a bank spring rest api, which after the user logs in, their details will be available for frontend to use.

I am really confused on how to structure this program as I want it so that the front end which consumes the api retrieves your data.

I know how to implement the controllers etc, however when implementing spring security, would I have all the fields including balance, transaction count, creation date etc in the User class which spring security uses for login, or would I have it in a separate DTO class.

I've done some research on Baeldungs website but I'm still really confused for my use case.

Im new to Spring REST, any advice would be appreciated

Comment: Just implement it as you normally would do. Why would that change when you add security?

Comment: basically with security I would have a user table right? Would I have all my user details within that user class or would I only use the user table for username, password and roles

Comment: Again why would it change... Why if you start using security all your transaction information should suddenly move to the user table? Why? What makes you think that should happen?

Comment: @sullyh7 you can have whatever is required business wise in that UserDto. The important thing though is that the controller is allowed to disclose only information of the current user and not other users ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there should be clear separation between domain model and data model.
If your application demands that for each transaction that may be initiated from the front end, balance, transaction count needs to be used, then you can put these details in your `Authentication` object. But in case they don't, please go ahead with minimum set of attributes that are absolutely requried for each transaction - `userId` / `bankId` / `clientId`.

With this sorted out, your application can send a `GET /user` request on front end application initialization where you can pull all details that are required at front end.

**TLDR**: Store attributes that are required in each request and which should never come from user - logged in user id - in `SecurityContext` as these end up in `Session` object. For everything else, you can trigger a `GET` request to fetch and cache it on your front end application.